# Dynamically create textbox on click button, and change it's css properties for selected textbox

Tags: javascript

Thanks once again,for all great mind's.

My expectation is exactly what the they have in example site.

example site:
http://www.printvenue.com/customer-design/editor/rounded-corner-business-cards/3-0128-vc-psd

--->creating text box dynamically onclick in CANVAS area only.

--->text box input text's font,font size,color .. changed by getting id
var somename = document.getelementbyid("id of textbox -in this case id getting uniquely");
 somename = here all function for changing color, font are follows

but,

my problem is to  add text box dynamically onclick button,so how to assing id for 
var somename = document.getelementbyid("id of textbox(dynamically created text box id)");

At the same time that text box should be movable any were in canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Here the `link` that you wanted :

[**JavaScript Version:**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/RanWJ/3/)

**HTML**

```
<input id='inp' type='button' value='Click me'/>
<div id='cont'>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('inp').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
        textarea.className="mytextbox";
        document.getElementById('cont').appendChild(textarea);
    });
```

**Css**

```
.mytextbox{
    width:200px;height:200px;box-shadow:2px 1px 5px 1px #000;

}
```

---

[**jQuery Version :**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/DW2zy/)

**HTML**

```
<input id='inp' type='button' value='Click me'/>
<div id='cont'>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').click(function(){

     var textarea =  $('<textarea></textarea>');
     textarea.css({'width':'200px','height':'200px','box-shadow':'1px 2px 5px 1px #000'});
    $('#cont').append(textarea);

});
```

Comment: you are using jQuery, not javascript.

Comment: K let i convert it into PureJS..@Michel

Comment: I Update the link with JS @Michel

Comment: Thanks, But you didn't have to remove the jQuery version. Also, try to keep the code in the answer (The Fiddle is an amazing tool and worth to keep the link for live example), but the code in the answer make things faster for the reader

Comment: I also add the Jquery ..see the answer @Michel

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new HTML element like this:

```
var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
```

To add it to the parent use

```
document.getElementById([insert id of parent here]).appendChild(textBox);
```

This parent should be the div/html-element in which all the textareas are located.

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npH8X/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='parent'>
    <textarea>txt1</textarea>
    <textarea>txt2</textarea>
    <textarea>txt3</textarea>
</div>
<button onClick="addBox()">add textarea</button>
```

**JS**

```
addBox = function(){
    var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(textBox);
}
```

---

[Example in JSFiddle with JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/ueZ4s/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='parent'>
    <textarea>txt1</textarea>
    <textarea>txt2</textarea>
    <textarea>txt3</textarea>
</div>
<button>add textarea</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
        $('#parent').append(textBox);
    });
});
```